# I need help about array objects

Tags: php

For example I have this operation:

```
foreach ($data as $item)
{
    $arr[] = array(
      'subjcode' => $item->subjCode,
      'subjdesc' => $item->subjDesc,
      'lab' => $item->lab,
      'lec' => $item->lec,
      'units' => $item->units,
    );
}
```

How will I display the 5 of them in a row of a table using foreach like this (this code is wrong but this is what I want to do. What should be changed?):

```
foreach($arr as $val)
{
   echo '<tr>';
       echo '<td>'.$val->subjcode.'</td>';
       echo '<td>'.$val->subjdesc.'</td>';
       echo '<td>'.$val->lab.'</td>';
       echo '<td>'.$val->lec.'</td>';
       echo '<td>'.$val->units.'</td>';
  echo '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: nothing to do with yii, just put php in tag, it confuses

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display just the subjCode of the 5 elements then you need to do this:

```
echo '<tr>';
foreach ($arr as $val)
{
    echo '<td>'.$val['subjCode'].'</td>';
}
echo '</tr>';
```

This will display a `tr` element, then in a `td` each subjCode and then close the `tr`.

Note that although you are using an object when assigning variables in the array, the variable is set as an element of an array not as an object.

If we assume that $item->subjCode is "Hello" then what you are doing in the `$arr` is this:

```
$arr['subjcode'] = 'Hello';
```

If you want to use an object in an array, you need to change your assignment to:

```
foreach ($data as $item)
{
    $new_item           = new stdClass();
    $new_item->subjCode = $item->subjCode;
    $new_item->subjDesc = $item->subjDesc;
    $new_item->lab      = $item->lab;
    $new_item->lec      = $item->lec;
    $new_item->units    = $item->units;

    $arr[] = $new_item;
}
```

or

```
foreach ($data as $item)
{
    $new_item = array(
        'subjcode' => $item->subjCode,
        'subjdesc' => $item->subjDesc,
        'lab'      => $item->lab,
        'lec'      => $item->lec,
        'units'    => $item->units,
    );

    $arr[] = (object) $new_item;
}
$arr[] =
```

}

or if your $item element is not huge and you don't mind storing it, you just use this:

```
foreach ($data as $item)
{
    $arr[] = $item;
}
```

but then again, what is the purpose of the above, since you have the data already in the `$data` variable...

Answer (score 0):

You have rebuild your object to a array. So use:

```
foreach($arr as $val)
{
   echo '<tr>';
   echo '<td>' . $val['subjCode'] . '</td>';
   ...
   echo '</tr>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`echo '<td>'.$val['subjcode'].'</td>';`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to echo like that then:

```
foreach ($data as $item)
{
    $tempArray = array(
      'subjcode' => $item->subjCode,
      'subjdesc' => $item->subjDesc,
      'lab' => $item->lab,
      'lec' => $item->lec,
      'units' => $item->units,
    );
    $arr[] = (object)$tempArray;
}
```

then your echo should work;

You want to have a look [here](http://www.richardcastera.com/blog/php-convert-array-to-object-with-stdclass)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this.

```
$val = (object)$arr
```

Reference: http://www.richardcastera.com/blog/php-convert-array-to-object-with-stdclass